# IOS UILabel showing white line

Tags: ios, uilabel

I have the following implementation of a UILabel. I can confirm that there ins a NSString being passed in, but all I seem to be getting out is a white line

any ideas?

```
        CGRect labelFrame = CGRectMake(10, 5, 300, 20);                
        UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:labelFrame];
        label.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:15];
        label.text = labelText; 
        [textView addSubview:label];
```

Comment: Are you adding any other views on top which might be blocking some/all of this view? Have you tried doing something like a `label.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];` to make sure the frame is visible in your containing view? Are you trying to add your label to a `UITextView`? There could be some extra complications due to the fact it's a `UIScrollView`.

Comment: pls provide a screenshot. does anything else happen with the label? you can try to call `[label sizeToFit]` after assigning the text.

Comment: I set the background to green and now the whiteline is a green line. digging deeper it looked like the view above it was applying a margin. I can see my label now thanks DBD for that trick and everyone else who took a moment for me

Answer (score 0):

Try adding [label setAdjustsFontSizeToFitWidth:YES] (you must also set the minimum font size to something small).
Also, make sure the textColor value is not transparent and maybe give it some more height.
Don't forget to release the label if there isn't ARC enabled.